# nanopb - binary compatibility between different processor architectures

Tags: protocol-buffers, binary-compatibility, nanopb, infineon

I am using `nanopb`/`google-protobuf` between an ARM processor and Infineon Aurix.

**QUESTION**

Are there *possible* binary compatibility issues when communicating between different processor architectures?

Are there configuration flags that I could set, on both processors, to make sure encoding/decoding is done identically?

Comment: "ARM processor" is massively wide you have to be very specific. If the question is a protocol that is passing between them using a tool compiled to each platform, then it is a tools/protocol question as to the quality of the tool not the architecture.

Comment: this does not appear to be an arm question